# This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) in android manifest

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

Hi I m getting this error again and again. 
Process: pandaboo.run.carromking, PID: 30965
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pandaboo.run.carromking/pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor

the android manifest is as follow:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

there is no error in build but there is a red underline in the manifest under the .MainActivity with error:

```
This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (`pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity`)
```

pls help.

---

sure the MainActivity is as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
static Context context;
public final ThreadLocal<Discovery> disc;

{
    disc = new ThreadLocal<Discovery>() {
        @Override
        protected Discovery initialValue() {
            return new Discovery(Discovery.DiscoveryType.MDNS);
        }
    };
}

public static Publisher gamePublisher;
Subscriber gameSubscriber;
Thread testPublishing;
RenderThread renderThread;
private final Node node;

public MainActivity(Node node) {
    this.node = node;
}

public class TestPublishing extends Application implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (gamePublisher != null) {
            Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "run");
            //gamePublisher.send(message.getBytes());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.v("CarromGame:", "sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.v("CarromGame: exception", "in run");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                //tv.setText(tv.getText() + "o");
                Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "context view o");
                //contentView = true;

                renderThread = new RenderThread(new pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.displayComponents().getHolder(), new MainGamePanel(pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.this));
                renderThread.start();
            });
        }
    }
}

public class TestReceiver extends Receiver {
    byte[] msgb;
    String type = null;

    public void receive(Message msg) {
        msgb = msg.getData();
        type = msg.getMeta("CLASS");
        Log.v("CarromGame:umundo value", "TYPE = " + type);
        for (String key : msg.getMeta().keySet()) {
            Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", key + ": " + msg.getMeta(key) + " value for class" + msg.getMeta("CLASS"));
        }

        pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            //tv.setText(tv.getText() + "i");
            Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "context view i before");


            ObjectInputStream is = null;
            if ((type != null) && (!type.equals(""))) {
                try {
                    type = null;
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(msgb);
                    is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                    is.readObject();
                    Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "inside try block " + is.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assert is != null;
                Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "context view i after" + is.toString());
                renderThread = new RenderThread(new pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.displayComponents().getHolder(), new MainGamePanel(pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.this));
                renderThread.start();
            }
        });
    }
}

public class displayComponents extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public displayComponents() {
        super(getApplicationContext());
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        renderThread.running = true;
        renderThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }

    }
}

//Called when activity is created for the first time
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    // To check if there is any active Wifi connection
    if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
    }
    //Allow the application to receive Wifi Multicast packets.
    WifiManager.MulticastLock mcLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("gameLock");
    mcLock.acquire();
    System.loadLibrary("umundoNativeJava");
    Objects.requireNonNull(disc.get()).add(node);

    Log.v("CarromGame:", "on create");
    gamePublisher = new Publisher("Carrom"); //Carrom: channel Name
    node.addPublisher(gamePublisher);

    //gamePublisher.send();

    gameSubscriber = new Subscriber("Carrom", new pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.TestReceiver());
    node.addSubscriber(gameSubscriber);

    testPublishing = new Thread(new pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity.TestPublishing());
    //contentView();
    testPublishing.start();

    Log.v("CarromGame: umundo", "inside context view");
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //setTitle(title);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    MainGamePanel.PANEL_HEIGHT = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    MainGamePanel.PANEL_WIDTH = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_carrom_game_umundo, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the `pandaboo.run.carromking.MainActivity` class. The error messages explain exactly the issue: "the class has no zero argument constructor" and "This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)".

Comment: In a regular Java app _"This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)"_ would of course mean that you should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments). In Android you are not supposed to write any constructor for an `Activity` or to instantiate it yourself, so you need to find some other way to pass `Node node` to the Activity.

Comment: And any relevant code should be added to the question by editing it and not as an answer or as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

```
public MainActivity(Node node) {
    this.node = node;
}
```

Do not declare any constructors for an `Activity`. Only the Android framework can instantiate an `Activity` and you cannot define any additional constructors.

Comment: So, what needs to be done?

Comment: @gkns what do you mean?